# Python calling DLL: TypeError: 'LibraryLoader' object is not callable

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I am trying to import a DLL into Python 2.7.12 64 bit using ctypes. To narrow down the scope for errors I used Microsoft's MathLibrary DLL example and built my own based on these instructions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms235636.aspx). I built it as x64 release and copied the resulting dll into C:\ root to eliminate path length or spelling error issues. My machine us running Windows 7 Pro 64 Bit.

My python code is:

```
from ctypes import cdll, windll, c_long, c_int, create_string_buffer

test_dll = windll("C:\\MathLibrary.dll")

add = test_dll.add
```

When run it reports the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp.py", line 3, in <module>
    test_dll = windll("C:\\MathLibrary.dll")
TypeError: 'LibraryLoader' object is not callable
```

Can anyone advise what might be the issue?

Thanks

Andy

---

Update:

@eryksun comment  - this removed the LibraryLoader error. However I am now struggling to access the add function and get this error:

```
    add = test_dll.add
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 375, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 380, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'add' not found
```

Comment: In general it's better to use `ctypes.WinDLL("C:\\MathLibrary.dll")`. Or if the library uses `SetLastError`, use `ctypes.WinDLL("C:\\MathLibrary.dll", use_last_error=True)`. If you insist on using `windll` to load the DLL, use `windll.LoadLibrary("C:\\MathLibrary.dll")` -- a method that calls `WinDLL` but doesn't allow passing parameters to the constructor -- or either `windll["C:\\MathLibrary.dll"]` or `getattr(windll, "C:\\MathLibrary.dll")`, both of which cache the loaded DLL.

Answer (score 1):

windll is an object from the ctypes module. It can't be invoked like a function ('object is not callable'). You probably want to reference one of its methods and invoke it.

```
test_dll = windll.<func_name>("C:\\MathLibrary.dll")
```

you can use `__dir__()` to see the objects attributes and methods, or better yet, check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use 'cdll' would produce a similar error message "TypeError: 'LibraryLoader' object is not callable". Use 'CDLL' work well, so the problem is from case sensitive of the 'cdll' and possibly 'windll' as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
test_dll = windll.LoadLibrary("C:\\MathLibrary.dll")
```